# How to append a string from dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
X = corpus.get("Andrew Shapiro")

testsite_array = []

with X as my_file:

    for line in my_file:

        testsite_array.append(line)
```

where corpus is a dictonary and Andrew Shapiro is an item in it. It gives me following error.

```
  File "C:/Users/Vrushab PC/Downloads/Dissertation/untitled0.py", line 71, in <module>

 with X as my_file:

AttributeError: __enter__
```

Comment: What is `X`? Does it implement [the necessary `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) to be used as a context manager?

Comment: Stating @ChristianDean's concern a different way, what is the motivation for using a `with` statement on that dictionary value?   Why use `with`?

Comment: normally you would say "with open(filepath) as my_file:" filepath would not be a dictionary entry

Comment: I think you need "with open(X) as my_file:"

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the with statement, the object, X in this case, the object must have implemented the **enter** method and **exit** method. The whole point is that it allow for the object to clean it's self up even in the case of an exception. Think try:except:finally done much more cleanly.

In order to answer your question though, I would need to know what you expected X to be. You named your temporary placeholder for it as my_file so is X supposed to be a file path that you want to open or something?

A full example of what you are attempting to do would be helpful.

Generally though, you would use the with statement for doing things like opening files like this:
with open(X, 'r') as my_file:
    ...

Tahoe